# Can <!--more--> quicktag point to the beginning of the posts in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm wondering if there is a way to make `<!--more-->` tag link open posts at the beginning of the content and not as it is by default where it opens the post with a content located after that quicktag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Link_Jumps_to_More_or_Top_of_Page

Users can prevent the scroll by filtering the content more link with a simple regular expression.

```
function remove_more_link_scroll( $link ) {
    $link = preg_replace( '|#more-[0-9]+|', '', $link );
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'remove_more_link_scroll' );
```

Comment: You're welcome. I was looking for the exact same thing a couple of days ago. :)